# Adding row/column headers to NumPy arrays

Tags: python, matrix, numpy

I have a NumPy `ndarray` to which I would like to add row/column headers.

The data is actually 7x12x12, but I can represent it like this:

```
  A=[[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
      [1, 0, 3, 4, 5, 6],
      [2, 3, 0, 5, 6, 7],
      [3, 4, 5, 0, 7, 8],
      [4, 5, 6, 7, 0, 9],
      [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0]]


     [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
      [1, 0, 3, 4, 5, 6],
      [2, 3, 0, 5, 6, 7],
      [3, 4, 5, 0, 7, 8],
      [4, 5, 6, 7, 0, 9],
      [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0]]]
```

where A is my 2x6x6 array.

How do I insert headers across the first row and the first column, so that each array looks like this in my `CSV` output file?

```
        A, a, b, c, d, e, f 
        a, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5,
        b, 1, 0, 3, 4, 5, 6,
        c, 2, 3, 0, 5, 6, 7,
        d, 3, 4, 5, 0, 7, 8,
        e, 4, 5, 6, 7, 0, 9,
        f, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0
```

What I have done is made the array 7x13x13 and inserted the data such that I have a row and column of zeros, but I'd much prefer strings.

I guess I could just write an Excel macro to replace the zeros with strings. However, the problem is that NumPy cannot convert `string` to `float`, if I try to reassign those zeros as the strings I want.

Comment: Im not familiar with numpy but this would be very straight forward if they were just lists. Would a solution of that order be acceptable? can you convert numpy matrices to lists?

Comment: The way numpy matrices work, they can function as lists of lists, so you can iterate over them just fine on their own.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Numpy will handle n-dimensional arrays fine, but many of the facilities are limited to 2-dimensional arrays.  Not even sure how you want the output file to look.

Many people who would wish for named columns overlook the [recarray()](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.recarray.html) capabilities of numpy. Good stuff to know, but that only "names" one dimension.

For two dimensions, [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org) is very cool.

```
In [275]: DataFrame.from_items([('A', [1, 2, 3]), ('B', [4, 5, 6])],
   .....:                      orient='index', columns=['one', 'two', 'three'])
Out[275]: 
   one  two  three
A    1    2      3
B    4    5      6
```

If output is the only problem you are trying to solve here, I'd probably just stick with a few lines of hand coded magic as it will be less weighty than installing another package for one feature.

Answer (score 45):

With [`pandas.DataFrame.to_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html#pandas.DataFrame.to_csv) you can write the columns and the index to a file:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

A = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=36).reshape(6, 6)
names = [_ for _ in 'abcdef']
df = pd.DataFrame(A, index=names, columns=names)
df.to_csv('df.csv', index=True, header=True, sep=' ')
```

will give you the following `df.csv` file:

```
  a b c d e f 
a 1 5 5 0 4 4 
b 2 7 5 4 0 9 
c 6 5 6 9 7 0 
d 4 3 7 9 9 3 
e 8 1 5 1 9 0 
f 2 8 0 0 5 1
```

Answer (score 3):

Think this does the trick generically

Input

```
mats = array([[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    [1, 0, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    [2, 3, 0, 5, 6, 7],
    [3, 4, 5, 0, 7, 8],
    [4, 5, 6, 7, 0, 9],
    [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0]],

   [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    [1, 0, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    [2, 3, 0, 5, 6, 7],
    [3, 4, 5, 0, 7, 8],
    [4, 5, 6, 7, 0, 9],
    [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0]]])
```

Code

```
# Recursively makes pyramiding column and row headers
def make_head(n):
    pre = ''
    if n/26:
        pre = make_head(n/26-1)

    alph = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    pre+= alph[n%26]
    return pre

# Generator object to create header items for n-rows or n-cols
def gen_header(nitems):
    n = -1
    while n<nitems:
        n+=1
        yield make_head(n)

# Convert numpy to list
lmats = mats.tolist()

# Loop through each "matrix"
for mat in lmats:
    # Pre store number of columns as we modify it before working rows
    ncols = len(mat[0])

    # add header value to front of each row from generator object
    for row,hd in zip(mat,gen_header(len(mat))):
        row.insert(0,hd)

    # Create a "header" line for all the columns
    col_hd = [hd for hd in gen_header(ncols-1)]
    col_hd.insert(0,"A")

    # Insert header line into lead row of matrix
    mat.insert(0,col_hd)

# Convert back to numpy
mats = numpy.array(lmats)
```

Output (value stored in mats):

```
array([[['A', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'],
        ['a', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5'],
        ['b', '1', '0', '3', '4', '5', '6'],
        ['c', '2', '3', '0', '5', '6', '7'],
        ['d', '3', '4', '5', '0', '7', '8'],
        ['e', '4', '5', '6', '7', '0', '9'],
        ['f', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0']],

       [['A', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'],
        ['a', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5'],
        ['b', '1', '0', '3', '4', '5', '6'],
        ['c', '2', '3', '0', '5', '6', '7'],
        ['d', '3', '4', '5', '0', '7', '8'],
        ['e', '4', '5', '6', '7', '0', '9'],
        ['f', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0']]], 
      dtype='|S4')
```

Comment: I'm getting an error `'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'insert'` 
Any workaround suggestions?

Comment: Work around included. I converted the numpy mats to lists did the operations and converted back. Numpy insert routines are pretty stupid or I fail to see how they are useful

Comment: Thank you. I eventually figured it out with this.

Answer (score 2):

I am not aware of any method to add headers to the matrix (even though I would find it useful). What I would do is to create a small class that prints the object for me, overloading the `__str__` function.

Something like this:

```
class myMat:
    def __init__(self, mat, name):
        self.mat = mat
        self.name = name
        self.head = ['a','b','c','d','e','f']
        self.sep = ','

    def __str__(self):
        s = "%s%s"%(self.name,self.sep)
        for x in self.head:
            s += "%s%s"%(x,self.sep)
        s = s[:-len(self.sep)] + '\n'

        for i in range(len(self.mat)):
            row = self.mat[i]
            s += "%s%s"%(self.head[i],self.sep)
            for x in row:
                s += "%s%s"%(str(x),self.sep)
            s += '\n'
        s = s[:-len(self.sep)-len('\n')]

        return s
```

Then you could just easily print them with the headers, using the following code:

```
print myMat(A,'A')
print myMat(B,'B')
```

Comment: This looks promising. In trying to distill my question down, I confused matters, as the big matrix is not actually composed of labelled smaller matrices. I've tried to split it up and implement your suggestion but it's not working. For starters, I have a "list index out of range" at this line s += "%s%s"%(self.head[i],self.sep)

How would your suggestion change given that A is the only matrix, rather than dealing with a matrix that is a compilation of matrices?

Comment: I guess that you get an index out of range error due to different size of the matrices. Right now this code will only work with 6x6 matrices (i.e. len(['a','b','c','d','e','f'])). Just change the line that defines self.head to your matrix size (e.g. if your matrices are 3x3, the line should look like self.head=['a','b','c']). Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Not really sure, but you may consider having a look at [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/index.html).