# how to write a matrix to a csv file in python with adding static headers in first row and first column?

Tags: python, csv, matrix

I have a matrix which is generated after running a correlation - `mat = Statistics.corr(result, method="pearson")`. now I want to write this matrix to a csv file but I want to add headers to the first row and first column of the file so that the output looks like this:

```
index,col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6
col1,1,0.005744233,0.013118052,-0.003772589,0.004284689
col2,0.005744233,1,-0.013269414,-0.007132092,0.013950261
col3,0.013118052,-0.013269414,1,-0.014029249,-0.00199437
col4,-0.003772589,-0.007132092,-0.014029249,1,0.022569309
col5,0.004284689,0.013950261,-0.00199437,0.022569309,1
```

I have a list which contains the columns names - `colmn = ['col1','col2','col3','col4','col5','col6']`. The `index` in the above format is a static string to indicate the index names. i wrote this code but it only add the header in first row but i am unable to get the header in the first column as well:

```
with open("file1", "wb") as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f,delimiter=",")
        writer.writerow(['col1','col2','col3','col4','col5','col6'])
        writer.writerows(mat)
```

How can I write the matrix to a csv file with heading static headers to the first row and 1st column?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding row/column headers to Numpy Matrices](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11106536/adding-row-column-headers-to-numpy-matrices)

Answer (score 2):

You could use [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/). [`DataFrame.to_csv()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) defaults to writing both the column headers and the index.

```
import pandas as pd
headers = ['col1','col2','col3','col4','col5','col6']
df = pd.DataFrame(mat, columns=headers, index=headers)
df.to_csv('file1')
```

If on the other hand this is not an option, you can add your index with a little help from `enumerate`:

```
with open("file1", "wb") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f,delimiter=",")
    headers = ['col1','col2','col3','col4','col5','col6']
    writer.writerow(['index'] + headers)
    # If your mat is already a python list of lists, you can skip wrapping
    # the rows with list()
    writer.writerows(headers[i:i+1] + list(row) for i, row in enumerate(mat))
```

Comment: When I use this I see few values as empty. Actually some of values in my `matrix` are `nan` and I think thats why when writing they are getting empty. Is it possible I can write `0` in place of keeping them empty while writing?

Comment: Pass `na_rep='0'` to `to_csv`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a first variable to indicate the first line, and then add each row name to the row as it is written:

```
cols = ["col2", "col2", "col3", "col4", "col5"]

with open("file1", "wb") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    first = True
    for i, line in enumerate(mat):
        if first:
            writer.writerow(["Index"] + cols)
            first = False
        else:
            writer.writerow(["Row"+str(i)] + line)
```